# Hosting Scenarios and Configuration File Location

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis, asp.net-core, appsettings

I have just upgraded an app to RC2 and am testing all the hosting scenarios. I'm having trouble figuring out the best practice of how to setup the configuration of each scenario that they would all work.

Here are the scenarios:
1. Local debugging with WebListener (we need Windows Authentication)
2. Local debugging with Kestrel
3. Local debugging with IIS Express (+ Kestrel)
4. Published to IIS

I'm not sure if we need all these, but you know... developers and their preferences :)

So, when you publish the app to IIS, I've set up IIS application physical path to wwwroot-folder. The appsettings.json file is outside the wwwroot so I can load the configuration file using

```
new ConfigurationBuilder()
           .SetBasePath(Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), @"..\"))
```

This works fine. I have also setup the local self-hosted Kestrel and WebListener working directory to wwwroot so that the same logic applies there.

launchsettings.json

```
"workingDirectory": "wwwroot",
```

The problem is now with IIS Express. With IIS Express the current directory is the application root (same where appsettings.json is) so **with the current setup, it cannot find the settings file**. It seems that I cannot set a working directory for IIS Express(?) and this lead me to think that what is the preferred way to setup this that it would work in all of the mentioned scenarios?

Comment: In RC2 the location of the folder where web.config lives changed - it is no longer wwwroot but the approot (i.e. the parent of wwwroot). For IIS/IISExpress related questions a post I wrote might be helpful: https://blog.3d-logic.com/2016/06/08/running-asp-net-core-applications-with-iis-and-antares/

Comment: I managed to get everything working by checking the location of the config files and then using those directories for hosts. Not the prettiest solution, but it works. Will read your article to see if it could be improved.